# Should I fill out this request (and/or anything else) as instructed by the UK Embassy?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, visa-refusals, paperwork

I am Egyptian. I've applied for UK visa in October 2015. I got rejected. However, I only got a stamp on my passport, as per my travel agent, I didn't receive a official rejection letter. I am not sure if this is correct or not, despite, I would like to request a copy of my rejection letter as I've applied for a Schengen visa at the Swiss embassy and they have requested that I should present my rejection letter, also, I would like to have this letter for my own records. I've sent an email on the website of UK embassy. And I've just received a response to make a subject access request for information using this link https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration

However, I am not sure if this is the right process for my case. Please confirm. If yes, Is it only the standard subject access request form which I should fill in or should I fill in additional documents?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are unsure whether this is the correct process?

Comment: Hmmm...  were you scammed?  did you apply through an agent?  Did you actually go to a VFS and enrol your biometrics?  What does the stamp in your passport look like?

Comment: @DJClayworth, they do not send refusal notices to a 3rd party agent; they go directly to the end-user because the DPA is engaged.  The only exception is where the 'agent' is a member of the Law Society and has a registered power of attorney.

Comment: How could you have received a rejection and not the letter?

Answer (score 10):

You have been directly instructed by the UK Embassy to do so, so yes, of course you should. Fill out the request. Always follow the instructions given to you by embassy/consulate staff in situations like this.

> If yes, Is it only the standard subject access request form which I
>   should fill in or should I fill in additional documents?

Fill out the document(s) that were referred to in the email you mentioned in OP. If only the "standard subject access request" was mentioned, then that is enough. You will then be given a copy of the rejection letter, with which you can proceed with the new application. Continue to follow the instructions of the staff.